# How to backup the custom policies automatically

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When we're using the developer tool 'AAD B2C Custom Policy Manager' to do development work, all policies that we published there (production and development) are all listed in one place. And it's possible (unfortunately it happened) to click on the 'Delete App Policies' button by accident and all policies are gone. Then the whole authentication process is broken. Is there anyway we can backup the policies and restore them online? I know we can do this manually, just I'm wondering if there's a better/standard way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I should make that better, I removed the button on my personal version since I also clicked it by accident. The policies can’t be recovered as far as I’m aware.

I designed the tool for quick development not for production. In a real deployment use a CICD pipeline which pulls from a repo. This makes sure you deploy in a controlled way with rollback.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-devops